# onClick Animating not working? (Library)

Tags: android, animation

Today is my first attempt, to implent a library in to my Android project, and I choosed this [Android View Animation](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/32) library, it's really good, and it's works for onCreate, but if I want to implent it to my button, the animation actually not playing. What is the problem?

Here's my code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn)
                        .duration(700)
                        .playOn(findViewById(R.id.button));
                input.setText(null);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Szabaly.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
```

Comment: Probably because you are starting another activity and you can't see animation?

Comment: I try it without going to another activity, but there is no way to play it before going to in a another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't realize that "playOn" method is asynchronous. It means that next line of code will be implemented right after this method, without waiting until animation would be finished.

So go ahead with this code:

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(700).withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        input.setText(null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Szabaly.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
}).playOn(findViewById(R.id.button));
```